Efficiently store a dynamic CSV file in Python: dataframe or dictionary?
I have the following CSV file storing the composition of different groceries baskets: POME FRUITS, STONE FRUITS, FRUITS. As you can see below a basket can contain another basket (basket 'FRUITS' contains 2 units of basket 'POME FRUITS' and 1 unit of basket 'STONE FRUITS')
NAMES,QUANTITY

POME FRUITS,
APPLE,100
PEAR,200

STONE FRUITS,
APRICOT,50

FRUITS,
STONE FRUITS,1
POME FRUITS,2

Then I have another CSV file that stores the evolution of the price of each of the constituent of the first CSV file:
NAME,PRICE

AAPLE,2
PEAR,3
APRICOT,1
PEAR,4

I would like to compute the value of each basket of the first CSV file every time a price of one of its constituents changes. So the output should look like:
NAMES,VALUE

AAPLE,2
PEAR,3
POME FRUITS,800
APRICOT,1
STONE FRUITS,50
FRUITS,850
PEAR,4
POME FRUITS,1000
FRUITS,1050

For the CSV file with the basket composition, I created a tree structure and I stored it under a dataframe of columns
'Category', 'Constituents', 'Quantity' as below
Category       Constituents    Quantity  
POME FRUITS    APPLE           100
POME FRUITS    PEAR            200
STONE FRUITS   APRICOT         50
FRUITS         STONE FRUITS     1
FRUITS         POME FRUITS      2

Is there a more efficient way to store my initial CSV file considering that is can be thousands of rows?
To refresh the values of my basket at a defined frequency,I am re-reading in full the prices CSV file and restoring it in a dataframe each time.
But I am afraid of efficiency because the prices will become bigger and bigger.
1. How can I read only the new row in the prices CSV file (i.e. the 2nd CSV file) and thus avoid to read all the CSV file every time the price of a constituent changes?
Also I want to avoid computing the value of the baskets STONE FRUITS and POME FRUITS, each time I will have to compute the value of the basket FRUITS. I would like to just use the already computed values of STONE FRUITS and POME FRUITS.
So I create a dictionary that tells me if a constituent is a simple fruit or a basket of fruits. For example
{'APPLE': 'fruit',
 'PEAR': 'fruit',
 'APRICOT ': 'fruit',
 'POME FRUITS': 'basket',
 'STONE FRUITS': 'basket',
 'FRUITS': 'basket',
}

and for each refresh just recomputing the values of the elements in my dictionary and store them as the second value linked to my key as below
{'APPLE': ('fruit',2),
 'PEAR': ('fruit',3),
 'APRICOT ': ('fruit',1),
 'POME FRUITS': ('basket',800),
 'STONE FRUITS': ('basket',50),
 'FRUITS': ('basket',850)
}

The issue is that I would like to avoid to store the value of the basket 'FRUITS', as it is just the sum of baskets 'STONE FRUITS' and 'POME FRUITS'. But then for each basket  -in my big basket CSV - that will include the basket 'FRUITS', I will have to do the sum, and I think it could be inefficient,
On the other hand if I have to store the value of each basket A that I encountered, and then get this value from the dictionary each time I need it to compute the value of each basket B including the basket A, my dictionary size will be too big, and I am afraid there could be a memory issue.
2. Do you know an efficient way (in speed and time) to deal with such kind of data?
Thanks in advance

You should probably %timeit to see what is the best. I can suggest to update your csv prices from the top so you can use the nrows from pandas. But again i did not try to see if it is faster to read the first rows or to chunk read and only keep last chunk. (or using skiprows)

the csv file is managed by a provider and they are updating the prices from the bottom and I can't change how the csv file is updated.

It's very opinionated but I would say to use csv for data you persist and dictionary for in-code data, like your dictionary giving the last price and type of an object. As for reading you should try the several options and time them. (skiprows, chunksize, collections.deque)
